# transpose column to rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

My table looks like this

```
SurveyId    comments    val paramid
123     test1       100 1
123     test2       200 2
123     test3       300 3
456     test10      200 1
456     test20      150 2
456     test30      320 3
```

and am expecting something like the one below based on paramid

```
surveyid    comments1   comments2   comments3   1   2   3
123     test1       test2       test3       100 200 300
456     test10      test20      test30      200 150 320
```

Tried using pivot as below

```
select * 
from 
(
SELECT       
     surveyid   
     ,val
      ,comments 
      ,paramid
  FROM sample_table where comments is not null and surveyid = 123
) a
pivot
(
  max([val])
  for [paramid] in ([1], [2], [3])
) piv;
```

Can someone please suggest what is wrong with the above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this..It is simple and uses only a GROUP BY clause.(Tried in MYSQL and it is working fine)

```
SELECT
surveyid
,MAX(comments1) AS comments1
,MAX(comments2) AS comments2
,MAX(comments3) AS comments3
,MAX(COL1) AS COL1
,MAX(COL2) AS COL2
,MAX(COL3) AS COL3
FROM
(
SELECT
surveyid
,CASE WHEN paramid=1 then comments else '' END AS comments1
,CASE WHEN paramid=2 then comments else '' END AS comments2
,CASE WHEN paramid=3 then comments else '' END AS comments3
,CASE WHEN paramid=1 then val else '' END AS COL1
,CASE WHEN paramid=2 then val else '' END AS COL2
,CASE WHEN paramid=3 then val else '' END AS COL3
FROM test.sample_table
) TMP
GROUP BY surveyid
```

Result:
123 test1   test2   test3   100 200 300
456 test10  test20  test30  200 150 320

Comment: Please change the name of columns 3 and 4. It was a typo mistake.

Comment: you are able to edit your own answer by pressing the "edit" button on the left hand side directly below the answer.

Comment: Getting Error: Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Comment: This is how I created my sample table: `SurveyId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Comments` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `val` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `paramid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL .   The above query worked for me. Let me know your table datatypes.

Comment: For me survey id is int,and comments is varchar paramid is decimal, so it should work I believe. I guess the error is in MAX(comments1) AS comments1

Comment: Let me know if you are still having issue